# Add 2 static keys and valur to each inner array of 2 dimension array

Tags: php

I have a 2 dimension array with the help of Baba and now I am in problem again as I need to add [exam] => testOne and [exam_id] => 1 to all inner arrays

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Name 1' (length=6)
      'marks' => string '8' (length=1)
      'grade' => string '4' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => string '8' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Name 2' (length=6)
      'marks' => string '5' (length=1)
      'grade' => string '2.5' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => string '9' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'another name' (length=12)
      'marks' => string '8' (length=1)
      'grade' => string '4' (length=1)
```

I need to add 
[exam] => testOne and [exam_id] => 1 to all inner arrays want results as follwing

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'exam_id' =>'1'
      'exam' => 'testOne'
      'id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Name 1' (length=6)
      'marks' => string '8' (length=1)
      'grade' => string '4' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array
      'exam_id' =>'1'
      'exam' => 'testOne'
      'id' => string '8' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Name 2' (length=6)
      'marks' => string '5' (length=1)
      'grade' => string '2.5' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array
      'exam_id' =>'1'
      'exam' => 'testOne'
      'id' => string '9' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'another name' (length=12)
      'marks' => string '8' (length=1)
      'grade' => string '4' (length=1)
```

This is such a great place for learners like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
foreach ( $final as &$var ) {
    $var['exam'] = "testOne";
    $var['exam_id'] = "1";
}

var_dump($final);
```

If you want to retain the keys on top (As Requested)

```
$addOn = array("exam" => "testOne","exam_id" => 1);
end($addOn);
foreach ( $final as &$var ) {
    $var = array_merge($addOn, $var);
}
var_dump($final);
```

Comment: both worked bu add them in the end as Array ( [id] => 6 [name] => Student 6 [marks] => 9 [grade] => 4.5 [exam] => testOne [exam_id] => 1 I need in start Array ( [exam_id] => 1 [exam] => testOne [id] => 6 [name] => Student 6 [marks] => 9 [grade] => 4.5

Comment: If at the end would i be able to insert into mysql in CI as $this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);

Comment: position does not matter .. i can update it if you want ... @Saleem

Comment: That would be great if you would help me update. Thank you Baba :)